# Android ListView headerview can't respond to click event, sometimes when the headerview get focus by keybord mode, then click it in touch mode

Tags: android, events, listview, onclick

Android ListView headerview can't respond to click event, sometimes when the headerview get focus by keybord mode, then click it in touch mode.
Steps to repo this scenario:
1. scroll listview until the headerview disappear from sight
2. make the headerview get the focus by keyboard mode
3. click the headerview in touch mode
then the headerview can only respond to touch event, and  can't respond to click event. But in some device, this scenario can't occur.

Expect: the the headerview can respond to click event any time we see it

Android version: 2.2/2.3
Device: some devices with trackball or hard keyboard

I need the headerview can respond to click event any time. So someone can figure out the reason for this scenario? and give  me some advice to fix this?
Any tip is appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you using the onItemClickedListener on the list or onClickListener on a View inside the Header view?

Comment: yes, I am really using the  onItemClickedListener on the list, but the HeaderView also has a onClickListener for itself.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I don't know why it's acting weird, but I was able to solve the problem by not using `addHeaderView()`.

Just add a header from adapter as part of row: `mListView.setItemsCanFocus(true);`

```
@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    return position == 0 ? 0 : 1;
}

@Override
public int getViewTypeCount() {
    return 2;
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View v = convertView;

    if (v == null) {
        if (getItemViewType(position) == 0) {
            LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater)mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            v = vi.inflate(R.layout.music_list_header_view_2, null);
        } else {
            LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater)mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            v = vi.inflate(R.layout.music_favorite_list_row, null);
        }
    }
}
```

hope it helps!